# XCode 8 universal app: IB not showing all device resolutions

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode8

I have an iOS app that was designed only for iPad. Now I'm trying to convert it into a universal app. I'm using XCode 8.0 GM (8A218a) and the problem is that when I open the storyboard on the Interface Builder, it only allows me to select different iPad screen sizes and orientations, but no iPhone option is shown:

[image: Device Resolutions]

I already selected "Universal" on the Deployment info for the target.

The IB interface changed a lot from XCode 7.3 to 8, so my question is how to add the iPhones views to the storyboard.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the problem: I needed to check "Use Auto Layout" AND "Use Trait Variations" on the right panel. Those were disabled on the original app's storyboard.